# PHP $_GET values from url to array (custom function)

Tags: php, arrays, url, get

Lets say  I have an:

```
$url = "bla.php?test1=a&test2=b&test1=c&test2=d&test1=e&test2=f&test1=g&test2=h&test1=i&test2=j";
```

then I wish to run the custom **function getToArray("test1")** which would create an array with values ***["a", "c", "e", "g", "i"]***

I am trying to figure out how, but so far no luck.

Please note that in case of using getToArray("test**2**"), the last value from $_GET will be "j" which is end of the string...

Comment: Get string after `?`, explode by `&`, then explode each item by `=`.

Comment: Don't you think it will overright value of test1 in $_GET, there are multiple test1 present in the query string. Not a good practice!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do what you want. Basically it keeps exploding the `url`, first by `?` to get the query string, then that by `&` to get the individual key/value pairs, and then each of those pairs by `=` to get the key and value. If the key matches the search string, it is added to the output array.

```
function getToArray($url, $key) {
    $values = array();
    list (, $query_string) = explode('?', $url, 2);
    foreach (explode('&', $query_string) as $param) {
        list($k, $v) = explode('=', $param, 2);
        if ($k == $key) $values[] = $v;
    }
    return $values;
}
print_r(getToArray($url, 'test1'));
print_r(getToArray($url, 'test2'));
```

Output:

```
Array ( [0] => a [1] => c [2] => e [3] => g [4] => i ) 
Array ( [0] => b [1] => d [2] => f [3] => h [4] => j )
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/4bD5h)

Answer (score 0):

You can first remove first segments from url.

Then explode by `&` and then `=`

```
function getToArray($url, $key)
{
    $arr  = explode("&", $url);
    $temp = [];
    array_walk($arr, function ($item, $key) use (&$temp) {
        $d             = explode('=', $item);
        $temp[$d[0]][] = $d[1];
    });
    return $temp[$key];
}
$url  = str_replace('bla.php?', '', "bla.php?test1=a&test2=b&test1=c&test2=d&test1=e&test2=f&test1=g&test2=h&test1=i&test2=j");
$result = getToArray($url, 'test1');
print_r($result);
```

[Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/b6a7edfc7515eea93608d413c69d65b01639ffe2)